# C protecting against heap overflow

Tags: c, heap-memory

Consider the following function that is supposed to validate passwords:

```
char *systemkey = ...... ;


int validate(char* key) { 
 char* k = malloc(16); 
 char* sk = malloc(16); 
 strcpy(sk,systemkey); 
 strcpy(k,key); 
 return (strncmp(k,sk,16) ==0);
}
```

If `k` and `sk` are allocated consecutively, that it's easy to break the function by supplying 2 identical blocks of 16 bytes each.

If I'm the one writing the compiler/malloc/free/OS, is there any way I can identify **MOST** of these type of hacks and prevent them?

EDIT

One possible solution is to put some sort of canary word between each two different allocations. Is there another way?

Comment: You store passwords as *plaintext*?

Comment: Nobody would write that function, there's no point in allocating memory just to do a string comparison, and there's even less point in leaking the memory afterwards. Also, of course nobody stores passwords as plaintext.

Comment: The point is not the password thingy, it's how to defend against the heap corruption

Comment: what is problem with `return(strncmp(key,systemkey,16) ==0)`?. No heap required.

Comment: @Dayalrai I'm not trying to rewrite the function safely, it's just an example of how you can corrupt the heap

Comment: @Shmoopy 0)give example how he can do this 1)char* k = (char*)malloc(16); 2)use strncpy 3)actually no need to make copy for systemkey here in your case

Comment: @qwr if k is allocated from address 0 to 0xf and sk is allocated from address 0x10 to 0x1f then strcpy(k,key) , provided that k is composed of two identical 16 bytes blocks would overwrite addresses 0x10 to 0x1f and would result of sk being identical to sk

Comment: @Shmoopy use strncpy to avoid  overflow. also not that strncpy is not so secure too. u have to provide valid length

Comment: @qwr I don't want to modify the function. I'm trying to think of how would you modify the runtime/OS/compiler to identify these type of problems

Comment: @unwind This is not a real life code. This is just an example of heap corruption. I would like to know if the runtime could identify this.

Comment: @Shmoopy http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow_protection

Comment: Your best bet for this is probably going to be searching for relevant papers. [Google Scholar](http://scholar.google.com) is your friend when it comes to this since you can follow citations etc... that link relevant papers.

Two papers that look like they might help you to get you started are "Run-time Detection of Heap-based Overflows" from USENIX Lisa 03 and "HeapShield: Library-based heap overflow protection for free" from UMASS 2006.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best you can hope in use by and operating system is an implementation of malloc that randomizes the memory it returns. It doesn't prevent overflows, but makes exploiting them much harder. For large allocations a technique being used is to return the allocation aligned to the end of the page and leaving the next page explicitly unmapped as a guard page.

You can read a little bit [on this page](http://www.drijf.net/malloc/) and a the links from it to see how OpenBSD implements malloc protection. As far as I'm aware this is the best you can get from a malloc in an operating system in wide use.

Answer (score 0):

> If I'm the one writing the compiler/malloc/free/OS, is there any way I can identify MOST of these type of hacks and prevent them?

One possibility is to use a “sound” static analyzer that, if used properly, can guarantee that your program does not access any invalid pointer for any execution. Here is [one](http://frama-c.com/value.html).

Another is to use dynamic instrumentation. [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) is an example of this approach.